# How to make PDF undownloadable using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I found the [pdf.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js) project, which is very useful. However, I am unable to figure out how to remove the "Download" option.

Comment: Whatever user sees in a browser user can download.

Comment: Can you give us the code? I'm not interested in downloading the content from the website just to check it out for you.

Comment: https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js is older version of https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: @mishik can we download the content of src? 
<video class="video-responsive bg-dark" autoplay="" poster="/s/videos/5f6b72f30cf2d09aa32cb6d9/cover" src="blob:https://www.durgasoftonline.com/6302d93a-de88-4436-90a5-a5ae75cb17e3"></video>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Add jQuery library to shared folder.
2. Include jQuery library to viewer.html file
3. Add this on the header section:

   ```
   <script>
   $(function(){
       $('#download').hide();
   });
   </script>
   ```

Done!

Comment: $("#download").style.display = 'none'

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this easy snippet.

Comment: How can I download file which is rendered like this, with hidden Print button? Any suggestion? :p

Comment: The same: $("#print").style.display = 'none'

Comment: We can just disable the button and anyone can download the PDF using Ctrl+S

Answer (score 17):

just add this in viewer.css

```
.download
{
    display:none !important;    
}

.print
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: If just hiding the buttons, this should be the answer.. I don't understand why most developers are nowadays using a js or jquery fix to solve a CSS problem!
+1 to this answer!

Answer (score 13):

Just deleting the buttons breaks pdf.js.
You need to add a "hidden" class to them (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2611)

Comment: Brilliant very easy fix!

Comment: if we are removing these button need to remove the event listener also

Comment: Unfortunately everywhere I can find says "just add hidden class to buttons you want hidden", yet it seems this does not work [on many of the buttons, such as open] in newer versions of pdf.js and no issue reports regarding it. Would have been nice if they just did a check in the JS for the existing element before trying to attach code to it.. allowing the html to be freely adjusted without headaches.

Comment: How can I download file which is rendered like this, with hidden Print button? Any suggestion?  :p

Answer (score 5):

Modify the source. Line 85 of web/viewer.html.

https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.html#L85

Just remove the button.

```
  <button id="download" title="Download" onclick="PDFView.download();" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <img src="images/download.svg" align="top" height="16"/>
    Download
  </button>
```

This won't completely stop experienced and eager users from downloading it. You can never stop that. But this is enough to raise the bar enough for the curious.

Comment: Thanks @Joe Frambach, It worked! My intention is to stop at least average users

Comment: It is not working for me. When i remove this download button, Web page does not load the PDF.

Comment: @VivekSancheti Are you removing the entire download button element? The element spans lines 85-86-87-88.

Comment: Is there a way to stop any user from downloading the file?

Comment: @mak89k we need to encrypt it into our own extension just as amazon did with kindle ebooks, so that even if they download they cant access without proper decryption sequence(just my idea!)

Comment: @sathyam1992 That would mean when you are rendering the pdf you have to perform decryption each time leading to bad performance.

Comment: @mak89k not if we have an efficient algorithm to accomplish the task! Keeping performance aside is the idea still effective?

Comment: I would recommend adding a header parameter and check for that on the server side (requires server side processing of access rights for the pdf)

Comment: How can I download file which is rendered like this, with hidden Print button? Any suggestion?

Comment: This solution don't work ``secondary_toolbar.js:220 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at SecondaryToolbar._bindClickListeners (secondary_toolbar.js:220)
    at new SecondaryToolbar (secondary_toolbar.js:58)
    at Object._initializeViewerComponents (app.js:483)
    at Object.initialize (app.js:246)
_bindClickListeners @ secondary_toolbar.js:220
SecondaryToolbar @ secondary_toolbar.js:58
_initializeViewerComponents @ app.js:483
initialize @ app.js:246
Promise.then (async)
run @ app.js:539
webViewerLoad @ viewer.js:232``

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it actually looks to be using `pdf.customise.js` (a WordPress plugin that comes bundled with it does it this way). I did this to remove the openFile button.

First, in `viewer.html`, add this:

`<script src="pdf.customise.js"></script>`

Then, make your `pdf.customise.js` like so:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var params = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
        var disabledownload = false;
        var disableprint = false;
        var disabletext = false;
        var disabledoc = false;
        var disableopen = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var value = params[i].split("=");
            if (value && value.length == 2)
                if (value[0] == "disabledownload" && value[1] == 1) disabledownload = 1;
                else if (value[0] == "disableprint" && value[1] == 1) disableprint = 1;
            else if (value[0] == "disabletext" && value[1] == 1) disabletext = 1;
            else if (value[0] == "disabledoc" && value[1] ==
                1) disabledoc = 1
        }
        var extracss = "";
        if (disabledownload) extracss += " .download {display:none!important;}";
        if (disableprint) extracss += " .print {display:none!important;}";
        if (disabletext) extracss += " .textLayer {-webkit-touch-callout: none !important; -webkit-user-select: none !important; -khtml-user-select: none !important; -moz-user-select: none !important; -ms-user-select: none !important; user-select: none !important;} .selectTool { display: none !important;}";
        if (disabledoc) extracss += " #documentProperties {display:none !important;}";
        if (disableopen) extracss += " #openFile { display:none!important;}";
        if (disableopen) extracss += " #secondaryOpenFile { display:none!important;}";
        if (extracss) {
            var style = document.createElement("style");
            style.type = "text/css";
            style.innerHTML = extracss;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style)
        }
        $(document).bind("pagerendered", function(e) {
            if (disabledownload) $(".download").remove();
            if (disableprint) $(".print").remove();
            if (disableopen) $("#openFile").remove();
            if (disableopen) $("#secondaryOpenFile").remove();
            if (disabletext) {
                $(".selectTool").remove();
                $(".textLayer").remove();
                if (PDFViewerApplication) PDFViewerApplication.pdfCursorTools.switchTool(1)
            }
            if (disabledoc) {
                $(".documentProperties").prev(".horizontalToolbarSeparator").remove();
                $(".documentProperties").remove()
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

I don't like that this uses jQuery instead of pure javascript (however it could be easily rewritten that way), but still works really well.

Comment: Perfect Solution, Thanks 4oo4. I even added logic to disable bookmark button

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to add `hidden` class to the specific button in the toolbar (download button in this case)

PDF.JS has hidden class included by default in its CSS file. So just add a `hidden` class to the button which has the id `download` and `secondaryDownload`

Answer (score -1):

Add this to viewer.css:

To hide download icon:

```
.toolbarButton.download {
    display: none;
}
```

To hide printer icon...

```
.toolbarButton.download {
    display: none;
}
```

For both...

```
.toolbarButton.download, .toolbarButton.print {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try this https://github.com/latuminggi/pdf.js_readonly

this also prevent user from using shortcut like Ctrl + S or Ctrl + P

Comment: @KJ what browser do u use? anyway sometimes developers need to protect its pdf source file such as disable direct access (tool like IDM can sniff ".pdf"), or never reveal its original file name and .pdf extension, or encode pdf to base64 first, more documentation on PDF.js homepage, even nothing is secure but hardening the code is part of the job of developers themselves, cmiiw :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30665149)

Answer (score -1):

In viewer.js find download() and put return false; at the very top. If you also want to disable printing, do the same for beforePrint(), afterPrint() and performPrint().

Then you can hide the buttons using css, among other ways.

### Viewer.js

```
async download() {
    return false;
}
beforePrint() {
    return false;
}
afterPrint() {
    return false;
}
performPrint() {
    return false;
}
```