# Is there is any provision to disable to download when pdf or docs opened in new tab on react, is that possible in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdfview

I had a requirement in that pdf needs to be open in new tab but download should be restricted for some users.

I've came across few third packages on react none worked out well even rendering pdf file even If I can I need to have a provision to open pdf file or docs or excel.
Help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make PDF undownloadable using pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547956/how-to-make-pdf-undownloadable-using-pdf-js)

Comment: If the PDF file is sent to the client, it can be downloaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To open pdf in new tab:

```
<a href='/api/v1/print/example.pdf' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
```

Then use some conditional logic in the component to disable download if the user is not authenticated.

```
renderDownloadLink() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <a href="/path/to/your-pdf.pdf" download>
           Download PDF
        </a>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <p>You must be authenticated to download the PDF.</p>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiding the buttons does not prevent the content from being downloaded.

Comment: True. I'm guessing you would need to check user permissions?

Comment: Well once something is available to a user browser, it's on the client computer and one way or another the user can save the resource. It's not even possible to know that the client is using a web browser.