# How to display a pdf in django and not let it download

Tags: django, pdf, download

I have a pdf file uploaded to the site (the Internet library and the pdf file of the book in it), how can I allow viewing this file while only on the site and prohibit printing or downloading it. I will be grateful for tips or links to articles on how to do this.

Everything I have found on the Internet is not suitable because, the file can be downloaded and printed. I'm a beginner, so please don't laugh at my question.

Comment: You could try to convert it to html using something like pandoc. But it will be messy with complex pdfs. Other websites restrict to view the full document, meaning they just show let's say the first 50 lines and to see the rest you have to pay... Apart from that it is not feasible as said already. Even if you convert it to html people can still print it.

Comment: My operating system (Linux) gives me print to PDF functionality. Absolutely anything I can see in a browser window (or any other window with a print option), I can turn into a local PDF file.

Comment: There is no any way to 100% to prohibit copying of data that is shown on user on browser/ui. That's because users can screenshot, record the screen. But you can prohibit download, printing the pdf.

Comment: @Pycm This is what i need, to remove the ability to download and print a page of the book. Let them take screenshots, process them 300 times, or take these pages out of the browser console (although I know that there is a tool that allows you to output only text without a background to the console, and create this substrate separately on the site) The goal is not to give an ordinary (lazy) user to quickly get an electronic image of the entire book on his computer.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe not a complete answer. But you can use Pdfjs [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and hide download/save and print buttons like below.

```
.download
{
    display:none !important;    
}

.print
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Reference/more info:

Question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17547956/13861187)
Answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40374310/13861187)

Comment: As @Максим , This is what i need, to remove the ability to download and print a page of the book. Let them take screenshots, process them 300 times, or take these pages out of the browser console (although I know that there is a tool that allows you to output only text without a background to the console, and create this substrate separately on the site) The goal is not to give an ordinary (lazy) user to quickly get an electronic image of the entire book on his computer.

Comment: It sure gets downloaded internally. Otherwise, how would someone access it? The goal is not to give an ordinary (lazy) user to quickly get an electronic image of the entire book on his computer. As he say.

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying.

Comment: What? It's about downloading of PDF. sure 'disabled blind from reading my audio output' will come to the website and read it(listen) .